# adding pgadmin3 to windows start menu

Tags: windows, pgadmin, pgadmin-3

I have installed postgres (different versions actually) as well as pgadmin3 on windows using the package manager:

https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/package-manager/
https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/docs/pgcli/pgcli/

I also added the bin directories into the path environment on windows. Is there any way I can install program shortcuts to the start menu in windows?

Comment: Have you tried to click right button over "pgadmin.exe" and select "Pin to start"?

Comment: yes. and it worked. If you'd care to post it as an answer, I'd close the ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply right-click over pgadmin.exe and select "Pin to start".